# setwd error in R Studio for Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to Ubuntu but I have experience with R Studio before on Windows. On Windows, if I type `setwd("c:/users/me/desktop")` or whatever, I have no problems. However, with Ubuntu I keep getting `cannot change working directory` errors, such as if I try `setwd("home/me/desktop")` , `setwd("home")` , etc. Is there a certain way to change the directory in R Studio for Ubuntu?

Comment: `setwd("/home")` i.e. you need a leading forward slash

Comment: type the command `getwd()`. Look at how the file paths work in Ubuntu and then give it a go. Good luck\

Comment: including the forward slash at the beginning helped. I feel so stupid

Comment: that is a filesystem question than an R question ;)

Comment: It is always best to use ~ , which it the "home" directory (actually "/home/thisuser/" ) for current user on linux. For example: `setwd("~/Desktop/")`

Answer (score 2):

I use MacOS, in my terminal:
`> setwd("/home")`
`>`

So you can try `setwd("/home/me/desktop")`

Comment: including the forward slash at the beginning helped. I feel so stupid